# Random margin direction by Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, jquery-animate

I want randomly generate a margin direction using JS but nothing works. Whats wrong?

Here is my code

```
$('.portfolio-img').hover(function(event){
    var str = '';
    var myPos = ['marginLeft', 'marginTop', 'marginBottom', 'marginRight'];
    var thisRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPos.length);
    var str = String(myPos[thisRand]);

    $(this).find('img').animate({
        str: '-60px',
    }, 300);
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        str: '0px',
    }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(this).find('img').animate({
    str: '-60px',
}, 300);
```

to

```
var o = {};
o[str] = '-60px';
$(this).find('img').animate(o, 300);
```

As an aside, you can also replace

```
var str = String(myPos[thisRand]);
```

with

```
var str = myPos[thisRand];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   var animOption = {};
   animOption[str] = '-60px';

   $(this).find('img').animate(animOptions, 300);
```

You will have to cache `str` in `.data` and retrieve that in 2nd callback.